# How to prevent Ubuntu 18.04.1 unattended install using preseed from booting to language selection?

Tags: ubuntu, iso-image, language, preseed

I was able to setup a successful unattended install using Ubuntu 14.04 server (ubuntu-14.04.2-server-i386.iso).

However, when I attempt to do the same with Ubuntu 18.04 server (ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64.iso) it keeps on booting up and displaying the language selection.

How to I make the language selection disappear and show the main installation selection menu?

Comment: I followed the link below to create a new boot logo file and it worked.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196874/prevent-language-selection-at-ubuntu-installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PXE boot config file:

```
label server
        menu label ^Server
        menu default
        kernel ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
        append auto=true url=http://170.2.88.146 locale=en_US keymap=us interface=ens192 hostname= initrd=ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz vga=6 --- quiet
```

In preseed.cfg file:

```
### Localization
# Locale sets language and country.
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US

# Keyboard selection.
#d-i console-tools/archs select at
d-i console-keymaps-at/keymap select us
```